# Utilizar os valores digitados pelo usuário no asp.net c# webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, textbox

Criei um formulário para o usuário atualizar os dados de cadastro. Os dados "antigos" do usuário estão armazenados em variáveis de sessão que preenchem o formulário assim que o usuário clica em atualizar cadastro.
O problema é que ao gravar os dados no banco de dados são considerados os dados preenchidos pelas variáveis de sessão ao invés dos novos dados digitados no formulário.
Podem me ajudar a resolver isso? Obrigado.
Segue o código C#:

```
protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conexao = ConexaoDB.GetConexao();
        try
        {
            string comandoSQL = "UPDATE MA_USERS SET " +
            "nomecliente = '{1}', " +
            "facebook = '{2}', " +
            "website = '{3}', " +
            "cidade = '{4}', " +
            "estado = '{5}', " +
            "emailprofissional = '{6}' " +
            "where idcliente= '{0}'";

            comandoSQL = string.Format(comandoSQL, txtUsuario.Text, 
            txtNome.Text, txtFacebook.Text, txtWebsite.Text, txtLocal.Text, ddlEstado.Text, txtEmail.Text);
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" +comandoSQL+ "');</script>");
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(comandoSQL, conexao);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            conexao.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

E o código do formulário .aspx:

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 form-div">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="padding: 10px; padding-top: 50px; width: 400px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: #f6f3f3;">


            <h3>Update your informations:</h3>

            <p>Name:</p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome" runat="server" CssClass="textobox" Width="382px"></asp:TextBox>
            <p>Facebook:</p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFacebook" runat="server" CssClass="textobox" Width="182px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <p>Website:</p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtWebsite" runat="server" CssClass="textobox" Width="382px"></asp:TextBox>
            <p>Professional E-mail:</p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="textobox" Width="382px"></asp:TextBox>
            <p>City:</p>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLocal" runat="server" CssClass="textobox" Width="262px"></asp:TextBox>
            <p>State:</p>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEstado" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>


            <br /><br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnEnviar" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="btnEnviar_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblErros" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsuario" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Cadê o código???????

Comment: Coloquei o código. Obrigado.

Comment: Coloque toda a classe (tipo aonde está por exemplo o método desse botão `btnEnviar_Click`) preciso verificar o ciclo completo.